# Creating web server with express (node.js)

Tags: node.js, express

js and am trying to create a web server and server side code for my web application.

I understand express is used to get access to all static files.

I am trying to start a simple server using express as follows:

```
 var express = require("express");
 var url = require("url");
 var http = require("http");

 var port = 3000;
 var app = express();
 app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/Client"));

 http.createServer(app).listen(port, function(req,res){

 console.log("Server running at: " + "http://" + port);

 res.writeHead(200,{
 "Content-Type":"text/plain"
 });
 });
```

I cant seem to do anything with my **res** variable in my callback, which I am trying to use as a response object. Allowing me to do things like:

```
 res.end(¨hello world¨);
```

Is this callback even allowed, or how can I start sending responses etc. I am on virtual box (linux) machine, and using **res** always gives error (undefined methods etc.). Thanks in advance,

Comment: Express has some excellent documentation, have you looked at it?  Try http://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html to get started.

Comment: Yes thank you :) and why do people downvote all the time, it really effects reputation if you are just a beginner..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
http.createServer(app).listen(port, [hostname], [backlog], [callback])
```

There are no parameters given to the callback function. This is why req and res are `undefined`.

So you may change your code to:

```
app.listen(port, function(){
  console.log("Server running at: " + "http://localhost:" + port);
});

app.get('/', function(req,res) {
  res.status(200).send('Hello World!')
})
```

So take a look at the documentation of app.listen() and app.get()